# Create index to speed up query with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am using MS SQL and have two tables: Products (ProdID, some other fields) and ProdCat (ID, ProdID, CategoryID) which determines which Product belongs to which category.

And I am making select like

```
SELECT TOP (8) ProdID, Description, Image
FROM  Products INNER JOIN ProdCat ON ProdCat.ProdID = Products.ProdID
WHERE  Products.Active=1 AND ProdCat.CategoryID = 123 Order by ProdCat.sorting, Products.ProdID
```

Products table has more than 50.000 and ProdCat table has more than 150.000 records and the query is slow.

Can you please advise how to create index to speed up this query?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Nobody can offer an index here because we are lacking the details of your tables to be able to help. Can you provide the ddl for the tables and the existing indexes? It may be that an index isn't really the issue but without those details we can't do much.

Comment: You should post the actual execution plan for the query. You can easily get this from SSMS.

Comment: Look at the plan and see where the problem is. I can imagine several indexes that would optimize that specific query, but they'd be pretty specific to that query and not generally useful... but I can't know for sure without seeing table schemas, a plan, and knowing more about the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT TOP (8) ProdID, Description, Image
FROM Products p INNER JOIN
     ProdCat pc
     ON pc.ProdID = p.ProdID
WHERE  p.Active = 1 AND pc.CategoryID = 123
Order by pc.sorting, p.ProdID;
```

This is a bit challenging because there are two ways the query could be optimized.  First try `ProdCat(CategoryId, ProdId)` and `Products(ProdId, Active)`.

Unfortunately, neither is going o eliminate the ordering.  But this might improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

> ProdCat (ID, ProdID, CategoryID)

Why is there an ID column?  That doesn't seem helpful.

In a many-to-many linking table like this you need to be able to efficiently get all the CategoryIDs for a single ProdID, and get all the ProdID for a single Category.

Your query is a case-in-point of why.  If Products.Active has low cardinality, the query may start there, and look up the categories for each Active product, or it might start with Category=123 and then find all the products.

Then this table should have a clustered PK on (ProdID,CategoryID) and a non-clustered index on (CategoryID) (or vice versa).